# VSCode hangs every time I open yarn.lock file

Tags: visual-studio-code, yarn-workspaces

We started using latest yarn workspaces in our project. Since then every time I open (*accidentally*) `yarn.lock` file, VSCode hangs.

I tried closing folder, restarting VSCode but it always comes up.

[image: VSCode Hangs]